# How to change the page theme color in angular 11?

Tags: angular, sass, angular10, scss-mixins, angular11

I had an angular 11 application where I get the brand color from the API on the page load. With that brand color I want to add it to different components in my app for header, footer and different buttons styles. I created a brand.scss globally where I want to change the color of the header and footer here in this file. I'm able to get the color through the service in app component, but how can i export this to scss file. Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @rU17999: Could you please refer this post. I hope you would get some idea from it.
[MultiTheme Architecture/Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65281841/1189070). If you need some more input's please create some example at ```stackblitz``` would have some deeper look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Put color variables in JS and bind with ngStyle

Basically, if you are already using scss you can take advantage of SCSS variables which are different from css variables. SCSS is compiled to CSS during compile time, and SCSS variables are replaced with resolved value during compile time.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>angular-dynamic-theme</h1>

    <div class="block primary-background">Primary</div>  <br>
    <div class="block secondary-background">Secondary</div>  <br>

    Set Primary Color: 
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="primaryColor"> <br>
    
    Set Secondary Color: 
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="secondaryColor"> <br>

    <button (click)="changeTheme(primaryColor,          secondaryColor)">Save</button>
  `,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  primaryColor: string;
  secondaryColor: string;

  constructor() {
    this.changeTheme('red', 'yellow'); // Set default theme
  }

  changeTheme(primary: string, secondary: string) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', primary);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--secondary-color', secondary);
  }
}
```

**app.component.scss**

```
$primary: var(--primary-color);
$secondary: var(--secondary-color);

h1 {
  color: $primary;
}
h1:hover {
  color: $secondary;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.primary-background {
  background-color: $primary;
}

.secondary-background {
  background-color: $secondary;
}
```

if you are using Angular Material however this can be done way easier.
Hope this helps you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I dont have a button with different theme colors in my app. I'm getting primary color from the backend service, which i'm able to store it in the app component. Can i use the $primary variable in the child components scss files as well? And you said using angular material make things easy. Can you let me know that approach as well please?